# Simplify format of dotnest test in VS 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, xunit, coreclr

I just upgraded my project CoreCLR project from `project.json` to VS 2017 new project system.

I used to run `dotnet test` and be able to monitor the behavior of the test by the generated output.

Here is what this looks like now when I do this:

```
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9090123] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.Jsons"...)' (ID = '12c17a0046f4fbe9b16c1798e3057b5f02b112e2')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9096663] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.Jsons"...)' (ID = '24c3e96e41b952be76f4657d0c1a7a7a258ffd25')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9103176] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.Jsons"...)' (ID = 'd3707855dfae4131eabea842fa6e8465b214d084')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9109622] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.Jsons"...)' (ID = '16490b71e95b77e457f05e490a0cdb9404219d24')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9115769] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.Jsons"...)' (ID = 'c2225f8966c137f8778231513e9f60783cdf0c32')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9122278] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.obj.project.assets.json")' (ID = 'de7174b0a2323679ac7e95f73ef05d53e6d52e85')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9128720] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.CanReadAll(name: "FastTests.project.lock.json")' (ID = 'c5e178685f79e30802a445bbc9876b7b469ca86d')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9134546] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.FailsOnInvalidJson(invalidJson: "sssssssssssssssss{\"Name\":\"Oren\"}")' (ID = '485d46e96733356e1a84e0e6b834c649e58e2bf9')
[xUnit.net 00:00:01.9149860] FastTests: Discovered [execution] test case 'FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.UnmanageJsonReaderTests.FailsOnInvalidJson(invalidJson: "nnnnnnnnnn{\"Name\":\"Oren\"}")' (ID = 'b9268bfd32d924b6d2cf74b6f7bd33ca8e81310c')
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.6243807]   Discovered:  FastTests (running 1337 test cases)
[xUnit.net 00:00:02.9805881]   Starting:    FastTests (parallel test collections = on, max threads = 3)
        To attach debugger to test process, use process id: 1148
[xUnit.net 00:00:24.8661538]     FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.ConcurrentAccessTests.ConcurrentReadsTest [SKIP]
[xUnit.net 00:00:24.8664404]       RavenDB-6309
Skipped  FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.ConcurrentAccessTests.ConcurrentReadsTest
[xUnit.net 00:00:26.2805469]     FastTests.Client.Queries.FullTextSearchOnTags.UsingSuggest [SKIP]
[xUnit.net 00:00:26.2808014]       RavenDB-6573
Skipped  FastTests.Client.Queries.FullTextSearchOnTags.UsingSuggest
[xUnit.net 00:00:58.3486626]     FastTests.Server.Documents.Indexing.Auto.BasicAutoMapIndexing.IndexCreationOptions [SKIP]
[xUnit.net 00:00:58.3487989]        TODO - Efrat Indexes
Skipped  FastTests.Server.Documents.Indexing.Auto.BasicAutoMapIndexing.IndexCreationOptions
[xUnit.net 00:01:09.0771217]     FastTests.Blittable.BlittableJsonWriterTests.FunctionalityTests.FunctionalityTest2 [SKIP]
```

This is a huge wall of text, and the information provided for (I assume) the VS Test runner is obscuring any possibility of mine to actually see what is going on.

Is there a way to go back to the simpler output?

Comment: I see similar (but not as verbose) output with a trivial new unit test project (created using `dotnet new xunit`). Changing the version of `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk` from `15.0.0` to `15.0.0-preview-20170106-08` seems to help.

Comment: I upgraded to `15.0.0-preview-20170222-09` (don't have the 06 in the drodown), and doesn't seem to change it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had to set this:

```
"diagnosticMessages": false,
```

To reduce a lot of the clutter.